# tvOS 11 display issue

Tags: autolayout, tvos, tvos10

I am facing display problem with my app after updating my Apple Tv to tvOS 11. 
There is margin on 4 sides of screen.

Can Any body help me through this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the Safe Area in a UIView.

You can check it in Interface Builder -> [Size Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtOZa.png) whether the leading, trailing, top and bottom space is connected to the SuperView or to the [Safe Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ9sW.png).

Safe Area was introduced in tvOS 11